# How to group by month and find count using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to group the data by month (Created Date) and count the number of tuples for that month using python pandas.
[image]

Comment: What does it mean *the number of tuples*?

Comment: I mean the number of records for each month. I am trying to plot months and number of records chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
grouped = df.groupby(df["Created Date"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m")).size()
```

.dt.strftime allows for formatting the date as text, in this case year-month (%Y is the four digit year, %m the month)

Comment: I got error with your code- AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: You need to convert your "Created Date"-column to timestamp then - `pd.to_datetime` is what you are looking for.
`df["Created Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Created Date"], format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")`
You may need to adapt the format, I can only guess that there are no line breaks. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior for a description of the format.

Comment: The data has some errors, but your code seems to work, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for:

```
# Convert to datetime64 if it's not already the case
df['Created Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Created Date'])

df.resample('MS', on='Created Date')['Created Date'].count()
```

Comment: This is the error i get with your code- TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Comment: @RahulRamaswamy. I updated my answer, can you check it please?

Comment: I get an output now, but did not get the desired result. The output is 1 record with random numbers under each column name

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please? The value is the number of elements for a given month.

Comment: Still didn't get the desired output, this is what i got- Created Date
2013-10-01    111069
Freq: MS, Name: Created Date, dtype: int64

Comment: Nevermind, the data has some error i think, Thanks alot for the help